# I have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

the following message is displayed after a search performed by the php code below. I tried to check the mistake but i didn't find anything of useful. How to do? What's the problem? Thanks

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'field4 LIKE '%aaa%' ORDER BY filed1, field2, field3, field4' at line
>   1

The php code is:

```
<?php


//Get variables from config.php to connect to mysql server
require 'config.php';

// connect to the mysql database server.
mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);
//select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Cannot select database');

//search variable = data in search box or url
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
$search = $_GET['search'];
}

//trim whitespace from variable
$search = trim($search);
$search = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $search);

//seperate multiple keywords into array space delimited
$keywords = explode(" ", $search);

//Clean empty arrays so they don't get every row as result
$keywords = array_diff($keywords, array(""));

//Set the MySQL query
if ($search == NULL or $search == '%'){
} else {
for ($i=0; $i<count($keywords); $i++) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable " .
"WHERE field1 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'".
" OR field2 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'" .
" OR field3 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'" .
" OR field4 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'" .
" ORDER BY field1, field2, field3, field4";
}

//Store the results in a variable or die if query fails
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
if ($search == NULL or $search == '%'){
} else {
//Count the rows retrived
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
}

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<titleTitle of the page</title>";
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body onLoad=\"self.focus();document.searchform.search.focus()\">";
echo "<center>";
echo "<br /><form name=\"searchform\" method=\"GET\" action=\"search.php\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"search\" size=\"20\" TABINDEX=\"1\" />";
echo " <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Cerca\" />";
echo "</form>";
//If search variable is null do nothing, else print it.
if ($search == NULL) {
} else {
echo "Searched <b><FONT COLOR=\"blue\">";
foreach($keywords as $value) {
   print "$value ";
}
echo "</font></b>";
}
echo "<p> </p><br />";
echo "</center>";

//If users doesn't enter anything into search box tell them to.
if ($search == NULL){
echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Please insert a key to search</font></b><br /></center>";
} elseif ($search == '%'){
echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">Please enter a search parameter to continue.</font></b><br /></center>";
//If no results are returned print it
} elseif ($count <= 0){
echo "<center><b><FONT COLOR=\"red\">No result found</font></b><br /></center>";
//ELSE print the data in a table
} else {
//Table header
echo "<center><table style=\"text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  border=\"1\" bordercolor cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"4\" cols=\"4\" frame=\"border\" rules=\"none\">";
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<thead><tr>";
echo "<td style=\"sdnum=\"1040;1040;Standard\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#0049A3\" height=\"25\" valign=\"middle\" ><b><font color=\"#ffffff\" size=\"3\">FIELD1</span></td>";
echo "<td style=\"sdnum=\"1040;1040;Standard\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#0049A3\"  height=\"25\"valign=\"middle\"><b><font color=\"#ffffff\" size=\"3\">FIELD2</span></td>";
echo "<td style=\"sdnum=\"1040;1040;Standard\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#0049A3\" height=\"25\"valign=\"middle\"><b><font color=\"#ffffff\" size=\"3\">FIELD3</span></td>";
echo "<td style=\"sdnum=\"1040;1040;Standard\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#0049A3\" height=\"25\"valign=\"middle\"><b><font color=\"#ffffff\" size=\"3\">FIELD4</span></td>";
echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";


//Colors for alternation of row color on results table
$color1 = "#C1D6F0";
$color2 = "#C1D6F0";
//While there are rows, print it.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//Row color alternates for each row
$row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
//table background color = row_color variable

echo "<td bgcolor=\"C1D6F0\" ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE SDNUM=\"1040;1040;Standard\" ><FONT SIZE=2 COLOR=\"#000000\">".$row['field1']."</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"C1D6F0\" ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE SDNUM=\"1040;1040;Standard\"><FONT SIZE=2 COLOR=\"#000000\">".$row['field2']."</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"C1D6F0\" ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE SDNUM=\"1040;1040;Standard\"><FONT SIZE=2 COLOR=\"#000000\">".$row['field3']."</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"C1D6F0\" ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE SDNUM=\"1040;1040;Standard\"><FONT SIZE=2 COLOR=\"#000000\">".$row['field4']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";



$row_count++;
//end while
}
//end if
}
echo "</table></center>";

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
if ($search == NULL or $search == '%') {
} else {
//clear memory
mysql_free_result($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: You had to post *all* of your code? How about posting just the query?

Comment: Oh sorry but i dunno if the issue is in the query or other places of the code. Sorry

Comment: 1. Don't use mysql_* function they are depracated. 2. Are you sure that keywords are correctly escaped? Naming "field1", "field2" is really bad convention.

Comment: This isn't the original code. Note the differences between your error message `ORDER BY mdxc, name, surname, call`, and your code `ORDER BY field1, field2, field3, field4`. In your case, that is masking your problem. So why didn't you post the actual code?

Comment: @JohnConde most probably the error will be in line where he is using ORDER BY and LIKE

Comment: spit the query string out via echo. it will be obvious. let us know

Comment: Also, the word `call` appears twice in your error message, and not at all in your code.

Comment: Also, please format your titles to concisely describe your problem. I highly doubt **you** have an error in **my** SQL.

Comment: On the side note, I like the cabbage code, it will serve as a great example of how not to code the next time I'll have people that are in-training. No offense meant, but even the play projects grow, it's nice to add structure to your code, even if you're in the learning process :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example `CALL` is a [reserved word in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so you need to escape it using backticks:

```
`call`
```

Hard to tell exactly where without seeing your sql though.

Answer (score 4):

`call` is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You will need to wrap any columns named after reserved words in ticks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field1 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'
OR field2 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'
OR field3 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'
OR field4 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'
ORDER BY field1, field2, field3, field4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is in "MySQL syntax", focus on the query. This part of your code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable " .
"WHERE field1 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'".
" OR field2 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'" .
" OR field3 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'" .
" OR field4 LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'" .
" ORDER BY field1, field2, field3, field4";
```

seems to be your query, though I don't see the "where call like..." that appears in the error.

To identify the problem, I would add this line just before running the query:

```
echo $query."<br />";
```

Then you can see what query is actually causing the error. If there are other queries used, do the same. Find out which one is actually causing the problem.